# ADO Error "Unspecified Error"; No Error on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, excel-2007, ado

I'm using ADO in Excel 2007 VBA to return data from SQL Server. I'm aggregating lots of Select statements using Union All.

It's working fine for up to 110 aggregated Select statements, but at 115 of them I get the ADO error "Unspecified Error". At 110 Select statements it's returning about 7,000 rows and 255 columns, so its not an unusually large ADO recordset.

I thought ADO was probably passing on an error from SQL Server just as Excel VBA passed it on from ADO (I know that the error is from ADO, not VBA, because the error is shown in the ADO Connection object's Errors collection), so I sent the problem SQL statement with the 115 Select statements to my colleague who owns the SQL Server database being queried and asked her if she could tell me what SQL Server didn't like. However, it ran fine for her in the SQL Server query tool, and returned the expected data.

So it seems it's just ADO that doesn't like it when I go to the 115 Select statements; the SQL Server database itself is fine with it.

BTW I haven't tested with 111 - 114 Select statements; I've just narrowed it down to working fine with 110 and breaking on 115.

Any idea what the problem might be and what I can do about it?

For now I'm going to chunk it into sets of 50 Select statements as a workaround, but if it's possible to send it all at once I'd like to.

Here's the relevant code:

```
Public Const SQL_UNION_ALL_OPERATOR As String = " UNION ALL "

(the loop that aggregates the Select statements starts here)

            stSQL = _
            "select * from LikeItemExtract" & _
            " where Dept = " & varLikeDept & "" & _
            " and sup_name = '" & varLikeSupp & "'" & _
            " and VPN = '" & varLikeVPN & "'" & _
            " and Loc_Key = " & varCADLoc & "" & _
            " and SUPP_COLOR = '" & varLikeColor & "'"

            stSQLAll = stSQLAll & stSQL & SQL_UNION_ALL_OPERATOR

(end loop here)

    'remove the final " UNION ALL ":
    If Right(stSQLAll, Len(SQL_UNION_ALL_OPERATOR)) = SQL_UNION_ALL_OPERATOR Then
        stSQLAll = Left(stSQLAll, Len(stSQLAll) - Len(SQL_UNION_ALL_OPERATOR))
    End If

    If CBool(rs1.State And adStateOpen) = True Then rs1.Close
    rs1.Open stSQLAll, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

    iRecordsetRowCount = shAggData.Cells(1).CopyFromRecordset(rs1)
```

Thanks,

Greg

Comment: A massively more efficient approach would be to loop inserting the values into a temp table, then perform a *single* select joining all the fields to the temp table; `select * from LikeItemExtract inner join #temp t on t.dept=LikeItemExtract.dept and t.sup_name=LikeItemExtract.sup_name and ...` (or even constructing the inserts in the string)

Comment: @AlexK.: Thanks, but I'm not sure what the loop would look like. I mostly just us SQL when querying from Excel, so I have large gaps in my SQL knowledge. Also, it sounds like I'd be creating the temp table in the loop and then using it in the join; is that correct? If so, does the "#temp t" in your sample use an existing temp table t, or does it create a new one? If that syntax creates a new one, how do I use an existing one?